# how the solve the error Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, css, sql-server

I try to execute this code it will show the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException.Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

This is my code.in this code itself shows the above error..

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<%
   try{
       ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select u.post_id,u.userid,u.post_txt from requestdetails as r inner join user_post as u on r.frdname=u.userid where r.userid='"+id+"'");
      while(rs1.next()){

          int post_id=rs1.getInt(1);
          int fid=rs1.getInt(2);
          System.out.println("iiii "+fid);
          String text=rs1.getString(3);
          System.out.println("txttt "+text);

          ResultSet rs3=stat.executeQuery("select * from userdetails where userid='"+fid+"'");
          if(rs3.next()){
              String na=rs3.getString("username");
          System.out.println("username  "+na);
          String img=rs3.getString("profilepic");
          System.out.println("imgee "+img);
%>         
    <tr>
        <td width="5%" style="padding-left:25;" rowspan="2"> <img src="images/<%=img%>" height="60" width="55">  </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding:7;"><a href="" style="text-transform:capitalize; text-decoration:none; color:#003399;" onMouseOver="" onMouseOut="" id=""><%=rs3.getString("username") %></a>  </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>                      
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3" style="padding-left:7;"><%=text %></td> 
    </tr>
<%
    ResultSet rr=st.executeQuery("select * from comment_status where post_id='"+post_id+"'");
    while(rr.next()){
        int uid=rr.getInt("userid");
        String cmt=rr.getString("comment");
        ResultSet rrr=stat.executeQuery("select * from userdetails where userid='"+uid+"'");
        if(rrr.next()){
%>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td width="4%" bgcolor="#EDEFF4" style="padding-left:12;" rowspan="2">  <img src="" height="40" width="47">    </td>
        <td bgcolor="#EDEFF4" style="padding-left:7;" > <a href="" style="text-transform:capitalize; text-decoration:none; color:#3B5998;" onMouseOver="Comment_name_underLine()" onMouseOut="Comment_name_NounderLine()" id="cuname"><%=rrr.getString("username") %></a> </td>         
        <td align="right" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#EDEFF4">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td bgcolor="#EDEFF4" style="padding-left:7;" colspan="2"><%=cmt %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>   </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
<%
      }
}
%>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td width="4%" style="padding-left:17;" bgcolor="#EDEFF4" rowspan="2">  <img src="images/" height="33" width="33">    </td>
        <td bgcolor="#EDEFF4" colspan="2" style="padding-top:15;"> 
            <form method="post" name="commenting" onSubmit="return blank_comment_check()" action="commentstatus.jsp"> 
                <input type="text" name="comment_txt" placeholder="Write a comment..." maxlength="420" style="width:100px;" id=""> 
                <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<%=post_id%>"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value=""> 
                <input type="submit" name="comment" style="display:none;"> 
            </form> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>   </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>   </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"align="right" style="border-top:outset; border-top-width:thin;">&nbsp;  </td>
    </tr>
<%
   }
   }
   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
%>
</table>
</div>
```

I don't know what mistake I've done in above code.

Comment: Post the complete Stack Trace !!

Comment: This is the complete stack trace bro..  above </table> tag stack trace closed..

Comment: No it's not , it doesn't indicate at which line you are getting exception .. !

Comment: Check this , [How to edit my post ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work)

Comment: Thanks bro..i have done ..this is full code...

Comment: They are asking for an Error report. You will get it on the "Output" windows of your IDE. That error report is also know as the Stacktrace. Post the errors you see in Red color.

Answer (score 0):

I made the mistake of using the same statement for all queries.

When I created different statements object for the solution it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After I change the code like this, it's working fine...

```
Statement stt=con.createStatement();     
  ResultSet rs1=stt.executeQuery("select u.post_id,u.userid,u.post_txt from requestdetails as r inner join user_post as u on r.frdname=u.userid where r.userid='"+id+"'");
  while(rs1.next()){

   int post_id=rs1.getInt(1);
   int fid=rs1.getInt(2);
   System.out.println("iiii "+fid);
   String text=rs1.getString(3);
   System.out.println("txttt "+text);

      Statement st1=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs3=st1.executeQuery("select * from userdetails where userid='"+fid+"'");
       if(rs3.next()){
                    String na=rs3.getString("username");
                    System.out.println("username  "+na);
                    String img=rs3.getString("profilepic");
                    System.out.println("imgee "+img);
```

Comment: Explain about your change and why your code is working now ;).

Comment: you please just see my above error code.i n that code created the same object for the statement to all queries. and also not assign the object for the statement. that's why it shows that error.after i changed the code like create the different objects for statement to different queries it works fine..